# Trying to understand why this crashes when switch changes

Tags: ios, swift

learning Swift 3 - not sure why the code to change the background color of my button crashes the app.  myButton is a class variable and should be available to the function correct?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myButton : UIButton!
    var mySwitch : UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstView = UIView()
        firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view = firstView

        let myNewView = UIView( frame: CGRect(x:65, y:100, width:300, height:200))
        myNewView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        //myNewView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        //myNewView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        //myNewView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.view.addSubview(myNewView)



        let switchDemo=UISwitch();
        switchDemo.isOn = true
        switchDemo.setOn(true, animated: false);
        switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged);


        let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 144, height: 144))
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.ratingButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)

        myButton.addSubview(switchDemo);

    }

    func switchValueDidChange( sender:UISwitch){
        print("Switch changed")
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    func ratingButtonTapped(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        print("Button It Works!!!")
    }

}
```

Comment: When does it crash (i.e when you, the user, do what)? What line actually crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. You declare a class property but you don't instantiate it. I your viewDidLoad you just instantiate a local variable myButton, instead of instantiating the class property.

Here is a fix:

```
myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 144, height: 144))
```

Just remove the `let` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

First of all and strictly spoken `myButton` is an **instance** variable (actually a property) rather than a **class** variable.

`let myButton =` creates a local variable with the same name as the property but it is **not** the same object.

The solution is to omit `let`

```
myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 144, height: 144))
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not instantiate `myButton` anywhere in your code, therefore it stays `nil`.

You **are,** however, declaring a *local* variable called `myButton` in `viewDidLoad`.

You should replace your instantiation with this:

```
myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 144, height: 144))
```